# jQuery UI overlay not showing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

all. I am trying to get an overlay to work on my Modal box.

How can I create a working overlay?

I am using jQuery UI and have got it to work apart from the overlay.

Here is the code to call the module:

```
function showDialog(){
    $("#example").dialog();
    return false;   
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#example").dialog("center", "center", "center");
});
```

How can I call an overlay?

If you click the link Show the Dialog in the url below:

http://satbulsara.com/NSJ-LOCAL-02-06/eqs1.htm

Thanks,

Sat

Comment: Any chance you could post the code you're having issues with?

Comment: @ Andrew, I don't know how to call an overlay but I have posted what I use to call the module

Comment: if you know that would be fab!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make a dialog modal, all you have to do is specify `true` for the [`modal`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal) option:

```
function showDialog(){
    $("#example").dialog({
        modal: true // Make the dialog "modal" (show an overlay beneath the dialog)
    });
    return false;   
}
```

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)'s an example on jQueryUI's website.